# Need help with generating closed form solution to a sequence of numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

I am tasked with finding the closed form solution $f(n)$ such that the following are true

$$
f(0)=b+0c \\
f(1)=b+0c \\
f(2)=b+1c \\
f(3)=b+1c \\
f(4)=b+2c \\
f(5)=b+2c \\
f(6)=b+2c \\
f(7)=b+2c \\
f(8)=b+3c \\
...
$$

Basically, the constant term $b$ is always there while the constant term $c$ increases at a logarithmic fashion with respect to its input. I am having some trouble formalizing this concept into an equation however.

Can anyone point this humble undergraduate in the right direction? Currently I have the following, however I am not sure if it is correct and the `max` doesn't look very elegant.

$$
f(n)=b+\text{max}(0,\text{floor}(log_2(n)))c
$$

Comment: What is the pattern? Two zeroes, two ones, then four twos...?

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 It increases in a logarithmic base 2 fashion. So the next change is at $f(16)$ will be $b+4c$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try $f(n) = b + c\lfloor \log_2(n) \rfloor$ for $n > 0$, while $f(0) = b$.
This matches your logarithmic growth.